# CMake cannot find MSVC after compiler update

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm using VSCode (Version 1.74.2) on a Windows system.
My project requires CMake (v 3.24) and a MSVC compiler.

I had MSVC 19.31 installed, which worked fine with VSCode and the CMake kits (automatically found).

Today I needed to upgrade MSVC to 19.34. Luckily this didn't cause any issues, except for the fact that VSCode doesn't find the compiler anymore.

Obviously I cleared any build-directories, so there were no remnants to the old compiler in CMake-files. And the compiler installation was verified with the developer command prompt.

I tried to scan for kits, "Visual Studio Professional 2022 Release - XXX" (XXX = [x86|x86_amd64|amd64_x86|amd64]) kits were found. I selected the "amd64" kit. Configuring resulted in:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake-3.24.1/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:49 (message):
[cmake]   Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:
[cmake] 
[cmake]   cl.exe.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:9 (project)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
[cmake] CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

so obviously the compiler is not found.

I tried to delete the kits file and redo the scan. Adding the path in the C_Cpp > Default Compiler Path setting resulted in error.

```
Unable to resolve configuration with compilerPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64".  Using "cl.exe" instead.
```

Ah, yes I also rebooted the machine, started VS, closed and reopened VSCode (several times) - this stuff sometimes helps with Microsoft products, but not this time.

I'd be glad of any helpful comments.

Comment: That's CMake, and nothing to do with VSCode or VC++ ... Simple solution, edit the CMakeCache.txt file to point to the correct directory

Comment: @ChrisMM This is in the end CMake but at the beginning it is VS Code related. I will answer this once I get to a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with configuration files for your project that you open with VS Code. The `CMake` plugin for VS Code works in a way that it creates a minimum of two special files for your project:

- `c_cpp_properties.json`
- `tasks.json`

You are mainly interested in the `c_cpp_properties.json` file, this is an example file which I took from a different question that I answered:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

Yours will look similar.

**You are interested in the element (usually at the bottom) called** `compilerPath`.

Since you updated `MSVC` to a newer version you are still passing the wrong path here (I can tell you upgraded from 14.xxx).

By correcting the path to the newer version you will most likely fix your issue.

**NOTE:** You may need to update more of these variables (maybe even in both files). However this is where your issues stem from.

Comment: With the CMakeTools addon can you delete the `c_cpp_properties.json` and have it regenerate that file or doesn't that work?

Comment: From my general experience it's a hit or miss. If he does a proper reinstall of CMake tools for development via the Visual Studio installer and the CMake plugin (in this order). Then it will most likely work as well. From my experience the config files that generate these files just keep the old settings. So after a proper reinstall it should work (and just to be sure the deletion of the hidden vscode folders).

Comment: Well, changes in c_cpp_properties.json didn't make any change unfortunately. 
Uninstalling VSCode and re-installing it again (while removing *any* settings files and extensions) actually did change something.
Now it finds the compiler.
But CMake (in VSCode!) complains about it being broken (cannot compile a simple test program). 
Well - investigation continues...

Comment: @tooEarlyToGetUp Have you reinstalled the CMake development tools package via VS installer as mentioned in one of my comments?

Comment: @Milan Š I did that. What actually did the trick was 
1. Uninstalling VSCode and removing all Configurations
2. Time: After about 2 days after reinstall, VSCode started to recognize the compiler automatically.
I don't pretend I understand this, but since it works...

Comment: The behavior of the CMakeTools plugin is in general "random." I've checked their code some time ago due to a different question. And for example if you have correctly set toolchain files then half of what is in `c_cpp_properties.json` is just for show. So as long as you / it figured it out (itself) then it's great!